# AddFileAttachmentAsync returns 5005 when compose window is poped out in seperate window in MAC New UI

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

When taskpane plugin is poped out in a separate window in MAC Outlook New UI, the `addFileAttachmentAsync` API does not work as expected.
This is observed in the ScriptLab plugin also.

**Observed:** API returns `5005 (Operation failed because the data is not current on the server)` error code.

**Expected:** Attachments should get attached to compose pane.

**Environment:** MAC Outlook New UI

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Click on New message in MAC Outlook New UI.
2. Open ScriptLab Plugin (has a button to add any public attachment via addFileAttachmentAsync API)
3. Click on the "Continue message in separate window" button. (Taskpane will not close)
4. Click on the button (in taskpane) to add an attachment.
5. Error will occur and will be logged in the console.

```
error: 
    name: "Operation failed because the data is not current on the server."
    message: "Operation failed because the data is not current on the server."
    code: 5005
```

Comment: Does addFileAttachmentAsync API works for you when you launch add-in from pop-out window?

Comment: Yes, It does. This problem only occurs if add-in is already opened and after it is moved to pop-out window.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We have been able to reproduce this issue in the scenario shared. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.54.21091904 or later. When an updated build is available depends on the release channel a customer is on. The fix will close the TaskPane Add-in when compose window pops out. Please check https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/mac to get access to the latest Insider's builds.